# How to use replacement rules in a named expression before a sub-expression evaluates?

Tags: replacement, evaluation, expression-manipulation, semantic-matching

I have a named expression: `expr := a + b`. `a` and `b` are also named expressions.

Let's say `a := x + y`, `b := z + w`. This means that expr becomes `x + y + z + w`

At this point I want to replace `Plus` to `Times` in `expr` (but only in `expr`) to get `(x+y)*(z+w)`.

Can this be done?

Additional info: I have no control over how any of the expressions are defined. Ultimately this boils down to:

```mathematica
a := x + y
expr := a + b
b := z + w
(* I have no control over the code above. The order is not defined. *)
magic[expr, Plus -> Times]
(* (x + y) (w + z) *)
```

Is `magic` possible to implement?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to know what  an evaluatable expression means. Maybe "How to use replacement rules before a sub expression evaluates ?"

Comment: @userrandrand granted. I edited the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do his using "Hold" and "ReleaseHold" to prevent temporarily the evaluation:

```
Clear[a, b, expr]
a := x + y; b := z + w;
expr := Hold[a + b  ] /. Plus -> Times // ReleaseHold
expr

(* (x + y) (w + z) *)
```

**Addendum**

If expr can not be changed and is given e.g as; "a+b" then you can get the expression from "OwnValues" using "Extract":

```
Clear[a, b, expr]
expr := a + b;
a := x + y; b := z + w;

Extract[OwnValues[expr], {1, 2}, Hold]  /. 
  Plus -> Times // ReleaseHold
(* (x + y) (w + z) *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over how any of the expressions are defined. I'll add this to the question

Comment: I added a hack for this case.

Comment: This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
a := x + y
expr := a + b
b := z + w
```

---

**TL;DR**

You can use [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to block definitions of global variables including system variables.

Your example:

```
Block[{a, b}, expr /. Plus -> Times]
```

`(* (x + y) (w + z) *)`

---

**Further explanation and details**

To see what is going on here you can use [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) or [`Echo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html)

```
Block[{a, b}, Print[expr]; expr /. Plus -> Times]
```

printed output : `a+b`

So `Block` is doing it's job of blocking the definitions of `a` and `b`. This is only **temporary** within the block. Once the `expr` is released into the wild of your notebook `a` and `b` regain their definitions.

To illustrate the power of `Block` more, consider doing the same with system functions:

A user defined function depending on system functions:

```
m = x |-> Sin[x]*Cos[x];
```

Say we want to turn `m[Pi]` to `Sin[Pi]+Cos[Pi]` rather than `Sin[Pi]*Cos[Pi]`

```
m[Pi] /. Times -> Plus
```

`(* 0 *)`

because of the `Sin[Pi]`.

`m[Pi] /. {Sin -> sin, Cos -> cos}` will not work either because `m[Pi]` is already evaluated by the time Mathematica tries the replacement.

Momentarily blocking the definitions of `Sin` and `Cos` so that they do not evaluate :

```
Block[{Sin, Cos}, m[4] /. Times -> Plus]
```

`(* -1 *)`

which is `Cos[Pi]`

Comment: This one is pretty cool and deserves an upvote, but doesn't work for my particular case, as I don't know what expr is composed of (a and b)

Comment: @BorislavStanimirov Oh so you really did need to check the own values. The question is misleading then why not ask "how to modify the definition of a function written by someone else in a package"

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are overthinking. It is better to use a function:

```
expr[op_, u_, v_] := op[u, v]
```

Now we can do

```
expr[Plus, a, b]
(*a + b*)
expr[Times, x + y, z + w]
(*(x + y) (w + z)*)
```

Comment: OP mentioned that they have no control over `expr`, presumably the actual problem is more complicated and expr is a complicated function inside a package that was made by someone else for example.

Comment: @userrandrand If `expr` is so complicated and OP does not have any control over it, then any of these solutions will fail. It's enough to have a couple of 'Plus' in the code. How would you indicate which `Plus` should be replaced with `Times`? To be honest, I cannot even think of a hypothetical situation where something like this would be needed.

Comment: Me neither but OP already mentioned in a comment to the accepted answer that they have no control over expr when an answer modifying expr was used. OP seemed happy with the method that changed the ownvalues of `expr`. Not sure what the actual context is just noting that a priori OP can not change `expr`

Comment: @userrandrand If OP is happy, I am perfectly fine :) But sometimes it helps to looks at the problem at different angle.

Comment: True maybe your answer might give a change of perspective. Let's see (:.

Answer (score 1):

another variation. I am using the nice trick for the initial simplify with side relation to work thanks to bmf shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277607/why-does-side-relation-work-differently-in-these-two-cases)

```
ClearAll["Global`"]
a := x + y
expr := a + b
b := z + w
```

And now

```
Times @@ Simplify[expr, {a == Unevaluated@a0, b == Unevaluated@b0}] /. {a0 ->a, b0 -> b}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]